# How do userspace programs interact with kernel moduels?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-kernel

*The motivation for this question is my try to figure out with which kernel module is the command `aplay sound.wav` communicating to play the actual audio file. If it uses the library functions for it, trace it to the library function".*

My current understanding is that the kernel modules provide an interface to the user space through device files in `/dev`. So I would expect to identify somewhere in the source code a stream form the sound.wav being sent to a `/dev/something`.

Is this an oversimplification of the real situation?

Answer (score 1):

ALSA's device nodes are located in `/dev/snd`. The logic to open individual device nodes is within libasound and follows (optionally) the rules set in `/etc/asoundrc` or `~/.asoundrc`.

I'm not sure if this helps you to find the specific kernel module. I'd use `aplay -L` to identify the hardware used and then `lsmod` to see which module it is.

Answer (score 0):

The ways user space can interact with the kernel are mainly the device files you mention and system calls. There are others like netlink, files in `/sys` and more.

Playing audio would be accomplished through a device file, yes. However, the device file may not be opened in the application directly, it may use a library to do that. In that case the program does open the `/dev` file, but you won't find that in the source code.

Another possibility is that it uses a sound server. It doesn't open a `/dev` file at all in that case, it just connects to a sound server to let it do that work.